# How to get minutes and seconds in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

Do anyone know how to convert timestamp data into minutes and seconds in Data Studio?

On the screenshot below you can see the possible data types we have in Data Studio, which do not have any seconds and minutes involved.

[image: minutes and seconds in Google Data Studio]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Data Studio provides a number of powerful functions that can be used inside of calculated field formulas. See the **[list of functions](https://support.google.com/datastudio/table/6379764)**.

In your case for getting minutes:

```
MINUTE(create_time, 'MILLIS')
```

*This function returns the minutes in `create_time` in UTC timezone.*

For getting seconds:

```
SECOND(create_time, 'MILLIS')
```

*This function returns the seconds in `create_time` in UTC timezone.*

And for getting minutes you could use the **[TODATE function](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300)** too.

```
TODATE(create_time, 'MILLIS', '%M')
```

*The TODATE function formats a datetime field according to the specified format.*

> More information on each function, including examples, is available in
>   the formula editor. This help will appear as you begin to type your
>   formula.

Do not forget to click on two links above for more explanation.